# Do I multiply the $a$ and $b$ or add first?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

in the question (key $a=4, b=-3$)

$$ab-4+b$$ do I times a and b or plus and what do I with the other $b$  and don't answer the question I want to work it out please help.

sorry for asking all these question but I don't have that much knowledge to answer questions. thanks in advance

Comment: $ab$ is shorthand for "the product of $a$ and $b$".

Answer (score 4):

$$ab-4+b = a\cdot b - 4 + b$$

When we see two terms juxtaposed, as in $ab$ or in $4x$, it means we take the product of the terms: i.e., multiply. So $ab = a\times b = a\cdot b$, just as $4x = 4\times x = 4\cdot x$.

You might be familiar with the acronym for the precedence in terms of the order of operations:

$$\text{PEMDAS: Parentheses, Exponents, Multiply and Divide, Add and Subtract}$$ In this case, we *multiply first*: $$\text{Evaluate}\;\;(a \cdot b) - 4 + b.\tag{1}$$

You can also factor out the $b$ term: $(a \times b) - 4 + b = b\cdot (a + 1) - 4$, which should give you the same answer when evaluated, as in $(1)$. Here, we would *add*/evaluate $(a + 1)$ first (parentheses), then multiply the result of $(a + 1)$ by $b$, and finally, subtract 4 to obtain the final answer.

Comment: This needs a TU! +1